# Running multiple AOT functions within function

Tags: halide

I'm trying to implement my template matching (with drawing) in AOT form and when I was testing whether the different methods work by including separate static libraries that are compiled from another project, I got build errors like:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2005 _ZN6Halide7Runtime8Internal13custom_mallocE already defined in template_matching_ccorr.lib(template_matching_ccorr.lib.obj) Halide Template Matching v2 AOT Run c:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Halide Template Matchign v2 AOT Run\Halide Template Matchign v2 AOT Run\template_matching_sqdiff.lib(template_matching_sqdiff.lib.obj) 1

Is there a way to be able to include multiple libraries and be able to run different functions?

Also is there a similar function as realize that can be used in a AOT compilation code or would that require me to make two different AOT functions (assuming I can call multiple functions to begin with)

EDIT: a quick fix seems to be adding  /FORCE:MULTIPLE to linker's command line

EDIT2: managed to get it to compile with adding

```
Target target = get_host_target();

target.set_feature(Target::NoRuntime, true);
```

to most of the pipelines except one which solves the multiple definitions. Now I'm wondering why I have to have one pipeline with the runtime even though I could just include HalideRuntime.h but it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

/FORCE:MULTIPLE works. So does judicious use of the no_runtime target feature. See http://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_15_generators_usage.html for details.

You can compile each pipeline without a runtime, and then link them together with a standalone runtime. Or you can just compile one of your pipelines with a runtime.

Comment: also in the jit version the entire code works but it requires to realize one pipeline... If i want the entire procedure in AOT version would I have to create 2 AOT pipelines and then call them as functions?

Comment: also the tutorial is written like a bash script. Is there a way I can compile just runtime and pipelines without runtime by using visual studio?

Comment: managed to fix the multiple runtimes. Please check the edited question

Comment: You'll need (A) one project to *build* the AOT generator, (B) a project to *run* the AOT generator and (C) a third project to build the final executable. Then set the project dependencies so VS builds them as A -> B -> C and does not try to build them in parallel.

Comment: I prefer to set the `HL_TARGET` environment variable instead of explicitly calling `target.set_feature(...)` because then I don't need to recompile to change any target features.